# How to get file from dropbox and upload on my server by using python

Tags: python, dropbox

I am working on application where I am giving a functionality to user where they can signin from dropbox by using my application but when I am trying to get the file from Dropbox I am unable to do it. When user choose the desired file from dropbox and click on choose and then nothing happen. Can anyone please help out either is it possible to do it or not? If yes, how can we do it? I am at beginner level. Please help me out and explain the whole process to do it in detail.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using public Dropbox files?

Then you just need to fetch the item by URL and download it. If this happens in a browser tool, you'll need JavaScript and not Python to download it.

Or you leave out JS and just use Python to render an HTML page where a button is for a Dropbox file and clicking the button triggers a download of the file. That is a generic HTML task you can search for.

If you need access to sign in Dropbox and view private files, consider using a Python library built around Dropbox.

Comment: Yes, user will view private files and choose from one of them.

Answer (score 1):

See the Python Dropbox guide. Are you using a library like that? Please share as your question was vague.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#

Also please share an explanation of what your logic is or a small code snippet. I can't see what you are doing yet so I don't know where you are missing something or making a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, I see you're using [the Dropbox Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser). That's a pre-built way to let your end-users select files from their Dropbox accounts and give them to your app.

Make sure you implement the `success` and `cancel` callback methods [as documented there for the Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser).

In the `success` callback, you'll get the information for the selected file(s). That occurs in JavaScript in the browser though, so if you need that on your server, you'll need to write some JavaScript to send that up to your server, e.g., via an AJAX call or a form or whatever means you use in your app.